# Unable to generate PDF with wkhtmltopdf on a headless server

Tags: python, html, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I have a HTML document that uses CSS files and a around a dozen PNG files generated out of `matplotlib`. To convert this HTML document into a PDF, I installed `wkhtmltopdf`, on a AWS EC2 Linux instance, in a manner described [here](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Using-wkhtmltopdf-without-X-server).

On the command line, this works

```
wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com output.pdf
```

However, the following Python snippet does not work.

```
reportCss = pathlib.Path(os.path.join(cssDir, 'report.css'))
w3Css = pathlib.Path(os.path.join(cssDir, 'w3.css'))
#
options = {
    'page-size': 'A4',
    'dpi': 720,
    'margin-bottom': 5
}
css = [str(reportCss), str(w3Css)]
pdfkit.from_file(htmlFilePath, pdfFilePath, options=options, css=css)
```

I get this error:

```
QPainter::begin(): Returned false
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dailyemail.py", line 55, in <module>
    main()
  File "dailyemail.py", line 44, in main
    pdfFileName = pdfgen.buildPdfDoc()
  File "/home/ubuntu/demo/py/pdfgen.py", line 58, in buildPdfDoc
    pdfkit.from_file(htmlFilePath, pdfFilePath, options=options, css=css)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pdfkit/api.py", line 49, in from_file
    return r.to_pdf(output_path)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pdfkit/pdfkit.py", line 181, in to_pdf
    '%s ' %(' '.join(args)),e)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Can you please advise what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that the PDF folder wasn't existing. The error message is mid leading.